# Hiding Keyboard not working for a Nested Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I am using below method for hiding keyboard

```
public static void hidekeypad(Activity activity)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

It takes input as 'Activity' and hides the keyboard whenever i tap on screen. It is working fine if the parent layout has no nested child layouts. But if the Parent Layout has nested child layouts and even if i do not use them still while tapping on the nested child layout. The Soft Keyboard is not hiding.

**A solution**  for this problem is to create listener for the nested child layout and call above method again . But is there any other method to hide the keyboard without setting the listener for inner child Layout.

Below is the Layout i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_img"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/register_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/register_header" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/register_header"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- this is inner child layout -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/upload_profile_image" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_userimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/user_image" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_first_name"
                    style="@style/edittextstyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_last_name"
                    style="@style/edittextstyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/last_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email"
                    style="@style/edittextstyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_new_pass"
                    style="@style/edittextstyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_confirm_pass"
                    style="@style/edittextstyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/cnfrm_password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_mobile"
                    style="@style/doneedittextstyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                    android:hint="@string/mobile"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="12" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/register_btn" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/cancel_btn" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside my activity i am doing

```
case R.id.rel_parent:
            Utilities.hidekeypad(ActivitySignUp.this);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this method to hide the keyboard :

```
   public void CloseKeyBoard(Context mContext){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY,0);
}
```

Hope this will help you